# Run local .html file in same directory as executable in web browser control (visual studio)

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I can't seem to run a local .html file on web browser control that's in the same path as the application directory. 
I am getting the current application directory, and adding my file name (such as "index.html") at the end of it however it doesn't build successfully. 
What's wrong with my code?

```
string applicationDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
string myFile = Path.Combine(applicationDirectory, "/Media/index.html");
webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("file:///" + myFile);
```

Comment: First of all `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/Media/index.html"` - is **not** _"in the same path as the application directory"_, it is in a `Media` subfolder of application directory. Next, what do you mean by _"it doesn't build successfully"_?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to browse with an url , but with a local file path :

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("../Media/index.html");
```